# Force Laravel queue to run different PHP version (Vagrant)

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, laravel-queue

My Vagrant box currently has the PHP version 7.3.1, however my project needs to be run on 7.2. I have altered the `Homestead.yaml` file to use 7.2 like so:

```
sites:
    -
        map: rcoa.local
        to: /home/vagrant/Code/rcoa/application/public
        php: "7.2"
```

And run:
`vagrant reload --provision`

However, I am still getting PHP 7.3 related errors when running my queue. Is there any way of forcing `php artisan queue:work` to use a specific PHP version?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this command inside your VM:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config php
```

than select PHP version you want to use:
[image]
[Source](https://tecadmin.net/switch-between-multiple-php-version-on-ubuntu/)

Answer (score 0):

Adding the php version to your sites in your `Homestead.yaml` only changes the php version the webserver uses, in order to change the php version the CLI is using you can run `php72` from the command line.

After that your queue should be run with the specified php version.

Comment: Hi, I've tried running `php7.2 artisan queue:work` which is failing, however nothing is being written to my laravel.log file - is this usual behaviour?